# Power query SSL data source error

Tags: excel, ssl, powerquery

I have an excel workbook with a power query connection set to download an excel workbook from the Jotform report tool.
(Power query->From File->From Excel->https://www.jotform.com/excel/62736196700000)
****Link was modified to protect data***

I have no problem running it on Office 2013 with Power Query plugin on Windows 7.

But then some users on Windows 10 with Excel 2016 report the following error: Data.source error: Cannot create a secure SSL/TSL tunnel.

TSL 1.1 & 1.2 is activated on both computer.

I'm kind of lost and I have depleted all my geek ressources on this one. Can anyone help troubleshoot this one?
I've activated the verbose mode on power query and I was able to pull out the error logs from a problematic computer.

Thank you very much.

**[EDIT]**
Log 1: [Here is the log from Excel:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1IMFe5CtXHNTRHLWFkS1F3eWc/view?usp=sharing) Log 2: See comment below... not enough rep.

Comment: In the traces is there a stack trace for the exception? Do the Windows 10 users have .Net 4 or later installed? Is TLS 1.1. or 1.2 enabled in Internet Explorer on those machines?

Comment: It seems like .net 4.5.2 is already installed. I tried to install it and it aborted telling me it was already installed.
TSL 1.1 and 1.2 are enabled in IE options.
Could some GPO restrict the use of .NET or the use of SSL/TSL?

Comment: What version of Power Query is being used in Excel 2016? You can find this out by going to the Data tab and going to New Query | Query Options, then going to the Diagnostics tab and looking under the Version header.

Comment: So i'm using version **2.43.4647.201 32 bits** on Windows 7, Excel 2013.
One of the problematic computer is using  the same version on Windows 10, Excel 2016.
At home, I use version **2.38.4491.181 64 bits** and it works perfectly.

Comment: Log 1: [Here is the log from Excel:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1IMFe5CtXHUVhJVm9YZ3pSNWc/view?usp=sharing) 

Log 2: [Log from Microsoft Mashup:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1IMFe5CtXHNTRHLWFkS1F3eWc/view?usp=sharing)